# How can you load a json file into localstorage?

Tags: json, local-storage

Is it possible to load the contents of a JSON file into local storage?
In my case, I have a JSON file that is an array of objects.  I would like to have the JSON file load into local storage when I start up an app, then I would like to access the array in local storage to display in the DOM.

Here is what I have found that seems to work.  I am new to this so I don't fully understand if this is the optimal solution.

```
var catObjArray = require ('./data/cats.json');
var newObject = JSON.stringify(catObjArray)
console.log(newObject)

// Put the cat array of objects into local storage
localStorage.setItem('catObject', JSON.stringify(catObjArray));

// Retrieve the cat array of objects from local storage
var catsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('catObject');

console.log('retrievedCatObjArray: ', JSON.parse(catsFromLocalStorage));
```

Comment: Pls show what you have done so far. How are you starting your application now

Comment: Added what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is fine, but you don' t need stringify and parse data to use storage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            
 $.getJSON('./data/cats.json', function(json) {
 

// Put the cat array of objects into local storage
localStorage.setItem('catObject', json);

createHtml();

   });

function createHtml()
{
// Retrieve the cat array of objects from local storage
var catsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('catObject');

  ...your code

};

</script>
```